# segfault when calling LoadEnvironment

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to embed node in C++ application. Compiled nodejs with `--shared` into `/opt/node<version>` prefix.

When I use node 9.2 my code works fine. However when I try the same code with node 9.3 I get a segfault on `LoadEnvironment`.

Here's the start of the code, you can view all of it [here](https://github.com/tebeka/embed-node) (switch `version` in the `Makefile` to see the bug).

```
  const char *argv[] = {"js"};
  int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(char *);

  uv_loop_t *loop = new uv_loop_t;
  uv_loop_init(loop);

  int exec_argc;
  const char** exec_argv;
  Init(&argc, argv, &exec_argc, &exec_argv);

  V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation("js");
  V8::InitializeExternalStartupData("js");
  Platform *platform = v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
  V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
  V8::Initialize();


  Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  Isolate *isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);

  HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  auto context = Context::New(isolate);
  Context::Scope context_scope(context);

  IsolateData *isolate_data = CreateIsolateData(isolate, loop);
  Environment* env = CreateEnvironment(
        isolate_data, context, argc, argv, exec_argc, exec_argv);
  std::cout << ">>> HERE <<<\n";
  LoadEnvironment(env);
  std::cout << ">>> HERE <<<\n";
```

Comment: looks like basic app, have you tried to valgrind it? it will show if the problem is in new version of lib